# Object initialization in C#

Tags: c#, .net, object, initialization

When i have declaration like:

```
class Professor
{
  string profid;
  public string ProfessorID
  {
     get { return profid;}
     set { profid=value;}
  }

  student st;

}


class student
{
  string name;
  string id;
  public string Name
  {
     get  { return name;}
     set  { name=value; } 
  }

 public string StudentID
 {
   get { return id;}
   set { id=value; }
 }

}


public void GetDetails()
{
  Professor prf=new Professor(){ ProfessorID=1, how to initialize student here?};

}
```

Inside GetDetails() how can i initialize student ?

Answer (score 5):

First make it accessible:

```
public student Student { get; set; }
```

then something like:

```
Professor prf = new Professor()
{
    ProfessorID = "abc",
    Student = new student { Name = "Marc", StudentID = "def" }
};
```

Note that if the property is get-only:

```
private readonly student _student = new student();  
public student Student { get { return _student; }}
```

Then you can use the alternative syntax (which sets properties without attempting to change the student reference):

```
Professor prf = new Professor()
{
    ProfessorID = "abc",
    Student = { Name = "Marc", StudentID = "def" }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `Professor` class will need a property setter for the student, at which point you can write:

```
public void GetDetails()
{
    Professor prf = new Professor { 
        ProfessorID = "1", 
        Student = new Student { Name = "Jon", StudentID = "1" }
    };    
}
```

Without that property, nothing in the `Professor` class will set the `st` variable at all.

Note that because in both cases we're only using the parameterless constructor, I've removed the explicit `()` from the object initializer.

Further note: automatically implemented properties can make your code a lot shorter:

```
class Professor
{
    public string ProfessorID { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StudentID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should make property Student in Professor:

```
class Professor
{
    string profid;
    public string ProfessorID
    {
        get { return profid; }
        set { profid = value; }
    }

    student st;

    public student Student { // New property
        get { return st; }
        set { st = value; }
    }
}


class student
{
    string name;
    string id;
    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    public string StudentID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }

}


public void GetDetails(){
    Professor prf=new Professor(){ ProfessorID="1", Student = new student()};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You  need an accessor for your student within Professor

```
class Professor
{
  string profid;
  public string ProfessorID
  {
     get { return profid;}
     set { profid=value;}
  }

  public Student {
     get { return st;}
     set { st=value;}
  }

  student st;

}


public void GetDetails()
{
  Student s = new Student();
  s.StudentId = someId;
  s.name = someName;
  Professor prf = new Professor { ProfessorID=1, Student = s;};
}
```

However, your current model is 1 Prof : 1 Student, are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Following up on John's answer:

You want parentheses, not brackets, but a public constructor is typically the right approach.  The other way to do it is a no-argument constructor with public properties.